# Как Создать Регистрацию, после которой будет создаваться Личный Кабинет пользователя?

Tags: php, sql

Всем привет,Как Создать Регистрацию, после которой будет создаваться Личный Кабинет пользователя?
Раньше никогда не занимался веб программированием, за неделю выучил все что нужно, сверстал сайт, сделал весь бэкенд, осталась регистрация с личным кабинетом, про сессии уже читал, но ничего это мне не дало, по этому прошу помочь мне разобраться более подробно в этом,возможно дать ссылки на примеры или на статьи, так как сам я ничего не нашел работующего.Заранее всем ответившим спасибо!

Comment: Если информация про сессии ничего не дала, то дальше смысла нет идти, сначала стоит про сессии понять смысл. Но вот интересно: как вы за неделю и сайт сверстали, и бэкэнд сделали, когда до этого ничего не знали? Можете показать какой-нибудь код?

Comment: @Alexxosipov когда в школе учился любил играть в игры по программированию,по этому все легко далось, какой код вам скинуть, у меня весь бэкэнд готов, а в регистрации у меня php+ ajax код, по сути все готово, но я прошу скинуть ссылки на статьи или вопросы с примером, где реализован личный кабинет пользователя, про сессии еще раз прочитаю, что по мимо сессий нужно знать, чтобы реализовать личный кабинет?

Comment: @Alexxosipov код вы можете посмотреть в других моих вопросах, он как раз из этого же проекта, а по регистрации кроме html + php кода нечего больше нет, в личном кабинете вообще только html пока что